# Doxygen: Empty Detail Description

Tags: documentation, doxygen, rtf, documentation-generation

Context - Doxygen tool on C codes to generated RTF documents.

In the documentation of Modules/Groups, we are getting the header "Detailed Description" even if no detail description is provided for some particular module/group.

In generated RTF document this looks ugly. Is it possible to get rid of this empty Detail Description sections?

I tried `"ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO"` but it is not working. I cannot do `"HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES"` as the group/module contains members (struct, functions ...) which are documented.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit late, however others may be interested (I was).

You can remove the group detailed description completely using the layout file, though if you have a brief description a `More...` link will still be created (which links to nothing). My solution was the disable brief description for groups and move detailed description to the top of the page (essentially replacing it).

Create a layout file by running the following command `dOxygen -l`. The creates the default layout file. The section we are interested in is groups, near the bottom:

```
<!-- Layout definition for a group page -->
  <group>
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
    <groupgraph visible="$GROUP_GRAPHS"/>
```

Now set `visible="yes"` to `visible="no"` in the `briefdescription` field. Near the bottom of the file you will see a `<detaileddescription title=""/>` Move this to the top, above or below `briefdescription`. You should now have:

```
<!-- Layout definition for a group page -->
  <group>
    <briefdescription visible="no"/>
    <detaileddescription title="Description"/>
    <groupgraph visible="$GROUP_GRAPHS"/>
```

Note that I've changed the title to "Description" by filling in the title field. Save the file. Now in your Doxyfile, you need to specify a custom layoutfile. Add the following line (or search for it and fill it in):
`LAYOUT_FILE=DoxygenLayout.xml`

Assuming your paths are correct etc, you should now have group pages with brief description replaced with the full description.

Answer (score 2):

The reason as to why "Detailed Description" gets generated even if there is no Documentation in the Entities (Modules/Groups, etc..) is because the Doxyfile tag **EXTRACT_ALL** is set to **YES**.

By Setting,

- **EXTRACT_ALL** = **NO**
- **ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC** = **NO**

Only the entities documented with Doxygen special comments will get Documented. And only those entities having @details -> Detailed description will be listed under the Detailed Description section.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't generate if the class has been documented like:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is..
/// </summary>
class ABC
{     
}
```

remove the 'summary' tags, i.e. it should be like

```
///
/// This is..
///
class ABC
{

}
```

search for detailed description(at the begining) in the link below
http://www.star.bnl.gov/public/comp/sofi/doxygen/docblocks.html