# C# - My Doxygen formatting isn't outputting correctly in the HTML file, what do I have to fix?

Tags: c#, documentation, doxygen

An example of my code with the comments to automatically generate the HTML file with:

```
    ///<summary>Starting at 2, up until the square root of 'x' (any factor larger than that would be too large), output all factors.</summary>
    ///<param name="factors">The list of factors.</param>
    ///<param name="x">The number to get factors of.</param>
    ///<returns>Returns a filled list of factors of 'x'.</returns>
    static List<int> CalcGCD(List<int> factors, int x)
    {

        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.Sqrt(x); i++)
        {
            while (x % i == 0)
            {
                Console.Write(i + " ");
                x = x / i;
                factors.Add(i);
            }
        }

        if (x > 2)
        {
            factors.Add(x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }

        return factors;
    }
```

And this is what it outputs in the HTML file:

```
Starting at 2, up until the square root of 'x' (any factor larger than that would be too large), output all factors.

param name="factors">The list of factors.

param name="x">The number to get factors of.

returns>Returns a filled list of factors of 'x'.

summary>Get the common factors between a_factors and b_factors. Loops through both, and if the value is the same it removes it once from both and continues the process.

param name="common_factors">The list of common factors.

param name="a_factors">The list of factors for 'a'.

param name="b_factors">The list of factors for 'b'.

returns>Returns a list of common factors and outputs them.

Definition at line 18 of file Program.cs.
```

Why is the XML still there? How do I make it go away?

Comment: Fixed it. The brackets (< and >) need to have a space inbetween them and the '///'.

Comment: @EpricBlargh  Put yr resolution in complete as answer, it might be helpful for others

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15226994/doxygen-empty-detail-description/16798300

Comment: See the doxygen documentation about "Documenting the code" and especially the part "Putting documentation after members".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using bold tags. My problem ended up being because the opening '<' was conjoined to the comment marker.

For me this worked:

```
\\! <b>bold text `</b>`
```

This did not:

```
\\!<b>bold text </b>
```